# Is the conditional expectation function of a convex function convex?

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, conditional-expectation

Let $y = g(X,U)$, with $(X,U)$ two random variables. Suppose that for all values of $U$, $g(x;U)$ is convex as a function of $x$.
It seems to me that the conditional expectation of $m(x) = E[Y|X=x] = E[g(X,U)|X=x]$ **does not** to be a convex function.

In fact, take $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and let $f(u|x) = f(U = u|X=x)$ be the conditional distribution of $U$ given $X$. Moreover, define $\tilde x = \alpha x + (1-\alpha)x'$. Then we have

\begin{aligned}
m(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)x') = m(\tilde x) &= E[g(X,U)|X=\tilde x] \\
%
&= \int g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)x,u)f(u|\tilde x) \,d u \\
&\le \int [\alpha g(x,u) + (1-\alpha) g(x',u)]f(u|\tilde x) \,d u \\
&= \alpha \int g(x,u)f(u|\tilde x) \,d u  + (1-\alpha)\int g(x',u)f(u|\tilde x)\,d u\\
&\ne \alpha m(x) + (1-\alpha)m(x').
\end{aligned}

Therefore, unless $X$ is independent from $U$, (i.e. $f(u|\tilde x) = f(u|x) = f(u)$) we cannot say that the conditional expectation function of a convex function is convex.

Is this right, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, take $g(x,u)=x^2-2u^2$ and suppose that $X=U$. Then $g(\,\cdot\,, u)$ is convex for all $u$ and $m(x)=\mathbb E[g(X,U)|X=x]=g(x,x)=-x^2$ which is not convex.